# howto set specific amounts of COLUMNS with POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

For purpose of reading Excels by using Apache POI XSSFWorkbook (XSSFSheet and XSSFRow), codes like this:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
```

*i* indicates difference rows, where the columns of each row are different.

My question is: **how can I assign the columns of the row, even some of the cells are blank.**

Comment: Did you [try reading the Apache POI documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator). If so, how far did that get you, and where's the code used? If not, what happens when you do?

Comment: Did not try iterating yet. My issue is that the row I got have been automatically assigned "correct" amount of columns, but the range is not good for other rows. I want to make the selection range all same for the whole sheet.

So, my range is is from 31-70, but the row cleverly detects the end of the row is column 60. So the nullpointerexception will come out. This make sense, but I don't want to deal with the selection in this way.